# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (HTTP/2.0 504)

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Nginx and Php-fpm 7.0 together with Amazon Cloudfront.

I am receiving this error on all of my static sources today out of the blue:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (HTTP/2.0 504)
```

and my site is not operational. Is cloudfront down or is there something wrong with my server?

Comment: It's a fairly safe assumption that CloudFront is not down.  A more likely explanation is that your web server is unresponsive -- HTTP error 504 is `Gateway Timeout` -- "the server (CloudFront) was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server (your Nginx server)."  Check your server's Nginx logs?

Comment: I checked: sudo tail -10 /var/log/nginx/error.log - didn't see much - any other logs i need to check ?

Comment: seems this was related to bots trying to bruteforce wp-login... is this a reasonable explanation ?

Comment: Yes, i think it would be an explaination. Gateway Timeout happens often to us when we got a surprising high load and Nginx cannot longer handle it. To avoid that, it would be better to have your stuff running in a cluster. Not sure if this is easily possible with Wordpress. You could try to block the callers IP address using WAF in conjunction to CloudFront. This would reduce load. What does memory/process count say?